# How to get data from the web into Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to figure out how I can import data from a web site into Tableau.  This is the link I am trying to get data from.

https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/default.htm

I am trying to use the Web Data Connector, but I don't think that's the right tool.  I'm not sure how to get the data into Tableau, or if it's even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I’d start by clicking Data Download on your web site and pulling a copy of the data in CSV format.

Comment: if it proves useful, and you want to avoid downloading to get updates, then investigate whether writing a web connector is worthwhile in your case.

Comment: I may use Python to do the downloads and plot the results in Python or Maybe Tableau.  I don't think Tableau can do this kind of thing.  Thanks.